# Swift iOS -NavigationBar and RightBarButtonItem not Showing

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, programmatically-created, rightbarbuttonitem

I looked on SO for the answer to this and couldn't find it. Programmatic really isn't my thing but I intend on learning it around the beginning of July.

I'm using Storyboards. I have a NavVC that has a RedVC as root and the RedVC pushes on a BlueVC. They are all connected by segues. I have a PurpleVC that is in the Storyboard but it is not connected to anything

```
NavVC->RedVC->BlueVC //segues

              PurpleVC //no segue
```

In my BlueVC I have a collectionView and I when I press a cell I want to modally present the PurpleVC which I'm doing successfully using:

```
BlueVC:ViewController, CollectionViewControllerDele..., CollectionViewControllerData...{

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let purpleVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PurpleVC") as! PurpleVC
        purpleVC.data = data[indexPath.row]

        purpleVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(dismissVC))

        navigationController?.present(purpleVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

@objc fileprivate func dismissVC(){
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

The problem is I don't get a `navigationBar` nor the `rightBarButtonItem` when the purpleVC is `presented modally`. I tried adding it to the PurpleVC's `navigationItem` in the collectionView's `didSelectItemAt` but nothing showed up so then I tried adding it in the PurpleVC's `viewDidLoad` but nothing showed up there either.

PurpleVC:

```
PurpleVC:UIViewController{

var data:SomeClass?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(dismissVC))
   }

@objc fileprivate func dismissVC(){
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

How come my `navigationBar` and `rightBarButtonItem` aren't showing when the PurpleVC is presented modally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are presenting a controller it wont come with navigation bar & items.
Go to your purpleVC storyboard file and manually add the Navigation bar and items.
Hope it will help!.

Comment: thanks for the help! I used nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: purpleVC). It was easier